# Bootstrap 4 - Vertically align a link with a form-group input

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap 4.  In the sample below, I want the link with text "issue" to center-align with the input control.  My sample approximately does this, but I am thinking there must be a more elegant way.  Suggestions welcome!  Thanks.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 form-group">
        <label for="theHours"><b>Hours</b></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="theHours" aria-describedby="hoursHelp">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 form-group d-flex flex-column justify-content-end mb-4">
        <a href="javascript:void()">issue</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4 form-group">
    <label for="theHours"><b>Hours</b></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="theHours" aria-describedby="hoursHelp">
</div>
<div class="col-4 form-group  d-flex  justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <a href="javascript:void()">issue</a>
</div>
```

we want to align the vertically means,we should add the **align-items-center.**

Comment: Thank you.  Actually - I wanted the link to center align with the input field, and not the vertical totality of the label and field.  If you have any guidance on that, it would be appreciated.